# Row embedding as output of a transformer - how are they defined?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, transformer

I am reading the paper [*Tabular transformers for modeling multivariate time series*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01843) and am having issues understanding the structure in Fig. 2. In Sec. 2.2, the authors say that the field transformer processes rows individually, creating row embeddings. What exactly is a row embedding?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm on Fig. 2 can de rephrased as:

1. Take $T$ sequential rows of data.
2. Omit random parts of the rows ([Random Mask](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SkgkJn05YX)).
3. Put each masked row separately into a Field Transformer. (It doesn't care about where the row was in the document.)
4. Put the resulting strings together as a sentence into BERT in the same order they were in the document.
5. Receive rows' embeddings that account for where they were in the document.

Regarding your question about the row embedding, it is a sequence of characters that were allowed in BERT.
Likely, it's a mix of Latin characters and numbers that would not look like an English word.

Comment: Thank you! To be sure I understood correctly: the resulting string you mention in 4 is a string where each input row element is expressed as a function of the other elements of the row?

Comment: I am not sure. If you took this transformer-related definition from some article, then maybe, but I still don't understand it fully. Let's call items in the row as x, y, z. Then the resulting string S is f(x,y,z), where "f" is aware of y and z when encoding x into a resulting string. From what I understand, you said x = g(S, y, z). As BERT is bi-directional, it might be true, but I need to read more on transfomers to say for certain.